# A=UL Doolittle method

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

A - symmetrical positively defined, matrx, 3-diagonal
Make a modified Doolittle method A=UL

U - upper triangular matrix

L - lower triangular matrix with ones on the main diagonal

I have to work on vectors not matrices. I think it is necessary to find any dependence and patterns but I don't see it.

Comment: Yes, I need to find U and L matrices. After that find x in Ax=b, and b is a vector.

Comment: It have to work for every square matrix A. I have to find an algorithm

Comment: Probably means tri-diagonal.

Comment: yes, exactly 3-diagonal